# Problem with Pytorch gradient of a non-sequential model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I have troubles reproducing this [Pytorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial).

The model they introduce is :

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()

        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        
        self.i2h = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.i2o = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, output_size)
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, input, hidden):
        combined = torch.cat((input, hidden), 1)
        hidden = self.i2h(combined)
        output = self.i2o(combined)
        output = self.softmax(output)
        return output, hidden

    def initHidden(self, batch_size):
        return torch.zeros(batch_size, self.hidden_size, dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True)
```

This model reproduces what is happening inside a RNN cell.

While coding, I had troubles with the gradient inside the model.

The code reproducing the issue is the following :

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# Toy data to reproduce the issue
toy_data_batch = torch.tensor([[0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0]], dtype=torch.float32)
toy_label_batch = torch.tensor([2, 0, 3], dtype=torch.long)

class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()

        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        
        self.i2h = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.i2o = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, output_size)
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, input, hidden):
        combined = torch.cat((input, hidden), 1)
        hidden = self.i2h(combined)
        output = self.i2o(combined)
        output = self.softmax(output)
        return output, hidden

    def initHidden(self, batch_size):
        return torch.zeros(batch_size, self.hidden_size, dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True)

# Model initialization
input_size = 2
hidden_size = 2
output_size = 4  # Targets in {0, 1, 2, 3}
batch_size = 3  # 3 data points in the batch
learning_rate = 5e-3

rnn = RNN(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
hidden = rnn.initHidden(batch_size)  # init hidden layer with zeros

# Negative log likelihood as it is classification
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()

# Forward pass
output, hidden = rnn(toy_data_batch, hidden)
#output, hidden = rnn(toy_data_batch, hidden) ### BUG: if I remove the comment here, It works

# Loss computation
loss = criterion(output, toy_label_batch)

# Backward pass
loss.backward()

print(rnn.i2o.weight.grad)  # This one is fine
print(rnn.i2h.weight.grad)  # This one isn't (has type None)

# This will fail, because of the None gradient
for weight in rnn.parameters():
    weight.data.add_(weight.grad.data, alpha=-learning_rate)
```

The output is :

```
tensor([[-0.1892,  0.0462,  0.0000,  0.0000],
        [ 0.1274,  0.1133,  0.0000,  0.0000],
        [ 0.1455, -0.2525,  0.0000,  0.0000],
        [-0.0837,  0.0930,  0.0000,  0.0000]])
None

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-5f02113fddf6> in <module>
     54 # This will fail, because of the None gradient
     55 for weight in rnn.parameters():
---> 56     weight.data.add_(weight.grad.data, alpha=-learning_rate)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

I've noticed that if I uncomment the line

```
output, hidden = rnn(toy_data_batch, hidden)
#output, hidden = rnn(toy_data_batch, hidden) ### BUG: if I remove the comment here, It works
```

everything works without a problem. It seems to me that there is a problem with the initialization of the variable hidden. As I've turned on the argument 'requires_grad', I don't know what to do.

Thank you in advance, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.i2h` has no gradient because it's not used in the first step of your model. When you back propagate, your model only uses `self.i2o` in the first stage, so `self.i2h` has no effect on the output. However, when you get to the second step, it utilises a `hidden` which has been calculated using `self.i2h`, so therefore there is a traceable gradient through that layer.

Comment: It makes sense. However, shouldn’t the gradient be zero instead of None ? 

Do you have any idea on how could I fix the issue ? The easiest solution I found is to make an artificial first pass on a batch of data full of zeros.

Comment: Gradients are initialised as None. You could just set them to 0 when you initialise the layer.